# Accessing Database Monitor on Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I usually access **Database Monitoring** directly from Apex to see my query costs: via SQL Workshop > Utilities > Database Monitor. It really is useful: it has a lot of filters and statistics relevant to optimize the application. It asks for a database account with a **DBA role**, which I give and I usually connect with no problem.

But for one of my applications, I just can't connect with it. I use the **system** account, which works on sql developer and sqlplus. For some reason, it keeps saying :

> Incorrect password or user does not have required role.

***I know the password to be correct*** and the user **system** has obviously the DBA role.

I tried looking in Administration Services > Manage Instance > Feature Configuration and copy everything from my others instances but nothing seem to work.

Any suggestion ? I use Apex 5.1 and Oracle 12c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I turns out it was only a **case sensitivity** issue.

I can connect with `SYSTEM` instead of `system`.